# Iterating over rows to separate rows with different values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I'm trying to write a function that works anonymously and dynamically to iterate over a data frame. 
This data frame is generated from a CSV file that is updated daily, it is a log of materials used. Some items will be used over again but some will be new and I don't want to write static code if another type of material is added later. 
Df example:

```
Date      Type Amount_Used
5/14/20     A  15
5/14/20     A  16
5/14/20     B  15
5/14/20     C  15
5/14/20     A  16
5/14/20     B  16
```

I am doing this to create an end of day report. So I need to account for all items that were used and how much of them were used. 
Items can vary from day to day and I could add different items down the road.

Comment: what are your comparing against, today's date vs all historical dates ? or do you have daily csvs ?

Comment: It a large CSV file that is appended to every time items are logged. At the end of each day though I have to know how many of each item were used along with the amount of each item used.

Comment: Then the answer below will solve your problem :) you can filter it by the max date to get the latest values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)** and find out details that you want:

```
In [389]: df.groupby(['Date','Type'], as_index=False)['Amount_Used'].sum()                                                                                                                                  
Out[389]: 
      Date Type  Amount_Used
0  5/14/20    A           47
1  5/14/20    B           31
2  5/14/20    C           15
```

where `df` is your dataframe.

This shows:

For the `date: 5/14/20`:

`3` Items(`A,B,C`) were used.
`Amount_Used` per Item that particular day.